# Why comparison of 40 is less than or equal to -2147483648 true?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am running the following code on my IDE using Visual Studio 2019:

```
cout << (40 <= -2147483648) << endl;
```

Both `40` and `-2147483648` are in the range of `signed int`, so there should be no over- or underflow.

I expect that the output is false.

However, the output is true.

Why?

Comment: @Harris Abdullah I can not reproduce. The provided reference used to close your question has nothing common with the code snippet you showed. You need to provide the actual code that produces this result.

Comment: @Harris Abdullah Please tell us which compiler/IDE you use.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I am using Clion as my IDE with the VS 2019 Compiler

Comment: @HarrisAbdullah I edited your question. Please check if I edited it in a way that you like.

Comment: I suspect that your compiler interprets `-2147483648` as `0-(+2147483648)`. `2147483648` is outside the range of `signed int`, so I suspect your compiler automatically interprets `2147483648` as `(unsigned)2147483648`. Because unsigned numbers are always `>=0`, the operation `-X` will cause an underflow. "underflow" means: The mathematically correct result is not allowed by the data type (`unsigned`), so the result in C differs from the "correct" one. You may try this: `(40 <= (signed)(-2147483648))` - that tells the C compiler that `-2147483648` is a `signed int` number.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Thanks for the edit, I got the solution, I am using long long instead of int

Comment: To clarify: There are no negative number literals in C++. You always first get a positive number that is then negated by the unary-minus operator. The positive decimal number 2147483648 is too large for a `signed int`, and since on Windows `long` is also just 32 bits wide, the compiler has to interpret it as an `unsigned int`. From there on, all evaluations are on unsigned numbers. If `long` were 64 bits wide, the constant would be a `signed long` and operations would occur with signed numbers.

Comment: @j6t "2147483648 is too large for a signed int, and since on Windows long is also just 32 bits wide, the compiler has to interpret it as an unsigned int". This is non-standard. The standard says the compiler should try `int`, then `long int`, then `long long int`. A decimal literal can never be `unsigned`.

Comment: @HarrisAbdullah which C++ standard are you using? That can't happen in C++11 in MSVC

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-standard feature (a.k.a "bug") of your compiler.

The C++ standard requires that decimal literals shall have one of these types:

- `int`
- `long int`
- `long long int`

The compiler should use the first type that can represent the value in question.

Your compiler, however, uses an unsigned type, which contradicts the standard.

Fortunately this behaviour can be disabled by using `/std:c++latest` compiler option (which you should always use, unless you have a specific reason not to).

Note, the Microsoft compiler does not disable this non-standard behaviour with `/std:c++14` and `/std:c++17` switches, although the requirements for the literal types are the same in these versions of the standard. Only `/std:c++20` or `/std:c++latest` switches are working.

If the non-standard behaviour is selected, and the warning level is set to `/W2` or higher, the compiler will warn you about applying unary minus to an unsigned value. [Always enable compiler warnings and treat them as errors](https://godbolt.org/z/o74d4aax7).

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o74d4aax7)

Edit: as noted in the comments, the actual compiler option that switches off the non-conformant behaviour is `/permissive-` (with the minus sign). It is implicitly set by `/std:c++latest` and `/std:c++20` but not by other standard conformance options. For more information about the option, see [the `/permissive-` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-190), though this particular document does not seem to mention this specific non-conforming behaviour. It is explained in [C++ Conformance improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/cpp-conformance-improvements-2019#standard-rules-for-types-of-integer-literals) instead.

Comment: More precisely, the relevant compiler option (to disable this non-conformant behaviour in MSVC) is `/permissive-`, see _Conformance improvements in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4:_ [_Standard rules for types of integer literals_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/cpp-conformance-improvements-2019#standard-rules-for-types-of-integer-literals)